# Conditional to check if array is equal to a particular value

Tags: c#, arrays

I am expecting this code to write "no hobbies" to the console. However, nothing is output. Why is this?

```
string[] hobbies = new string[0];
if (hobbies == new string[0])
  {
    Console.WriteLine("no hobbies");
  }
```

Comment: Arrays are reference types, that means, even if you create two arrays with the same elements, they are two different objects. If you want to compare the elements, you can use for example [SequenceEquals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-5.0)

Comment: If you just wan to check if the array is empty do `if(hobbies.Length == 0)` or using Linq `if(!hobbies.Any())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing arrays, `==` in this case compares **references** and not values. If you want to compare the arrays' content, you could use [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-5.0):

```cs
hobbies.SequenceEqual(new string[0])
```

Comment: Sure, but for readability, I'd rather use `hobbies.Length == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Array content can be compared using array.Equal(another_array) or array.SequenceEqual(another_array) .
try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] hobbies = new string [0];
        if(hobbies.SequenceEqual(new string[0]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no hobbies");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: The accepted answer already contains the solution you provided. Please edit your answer with further information if you believe it better answers the question.